# Solving an equation with exponentials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, quadratics

$$2^x+4^x+12=0$$

How exactly am I supposed to solve this? Am I supposed to get $x$ alone or solve it another way?

Comment: Hint: write $u = 2^x$ and find a quadratic in $u$.

Comment: Assuming that x is a real number, what do you know about any positive number raised to a real power (in this case $2^x $ and $4^x $) can it be negative?

Comment: In the future, please provide a more descriptive title; it makes it easier for users to help you. Also, users typically appreciate a more respectful tone than the imperative "solve this problem!"

Comment: If this is indeed precalculus . . . did you maybe transmute a `-` to a `+`?

Comment: What does "get $x$ alone" mean?

Answer (score 13):

For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $2^x > 0$ and $4^x > 0$, therefore

$$ 2^x + 4^x + 12 > 0 + 0 + 12 = 12 > 0 $$

Therefore there is no real solution.

Comment: but no condition is given in the question stating $x\in R$

Comment: @DheerajKumar The tag is "algebra precalculus", so what are the odd this is a complex variable exercise?

Comment: You are right. But otherwise specified I think it is reasonabe to  assume the convention $x$ denotes a member of $\mathbb{R}$ and $z$ denotes a member of $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 4):

let $u = 2^x$, then $4^x = (2^2)^x = 2^{2x} = 2^{2x} = (2^x)^2 = u^2$. Thus, $2^x + 4^x + 12 = 0$ becomes,
$$u + u^2 + 12 = 0$$
Using the quadratic equation will solve $u$, which is really $2^x$. To solve for the $x$, just take $\log$ on both sides of the solution, then after rearranging, you should be able to solve for $x$.

Comment: With the constraint that $u>0$...